# Is QR factorization continuous?

Tags: matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I can find sources on the internet that provides expression of the derivative of $Q$ and $R$ with respect to $A$ in the expression $A=QR$.
One such example is https://j-towns.github.io/papers/qr-derivative.pdf. However, I have not yet found a proof on whether $QR$ factorization of $A$ is continous in $A$. I guess this must be the case, since people take the time to diffrentiate it, and that wikipedia claim that it is numerically stable.

### More concretely:

Let $(A_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a series of real $m\times n$ matrices. By QR decomposition, define $Q_k$ and $R_k$ by $A_k=Q_kR_k$.  Let $\lim_{k\to \infty}A_k = A$ for some real $m\times n$ matrix $A$.  Let $A=QR$ by QR factorization.

Is it so that $\lim_{k\to \infty}Q_k = Q$ and $\lim_{k\to \infty}R_k = R$? Why? Does it matter whether all the matrices $A_k$ and $A$ has the same rank or not?

Comment: Related [question 4058385](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058385/continuous-qr-decomposition)

Comment: Also an older [question 3012511](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012511/if-q-kr-k-converges-to-qr-where-this-represents-their-respective-qr-decom?rq=1)